# M1 Mac Mini FaceTime with external USB microphone

Tags: macos, mac, facetime, apple-silicon, microphone

I have an M1 Mac Mini. I have purchased a Logitech C920 webcam/microphone to be able to make FaceTime calls. The microphone works when I use Photobooth or Quicktime to record a video. It also shows up in the sound panel of system preferences with the audio indicator moving up and down as I make noise.

As soon as I make a FaceTime call the microphone stops working. I've checked in the video menu on FaceTime that the right devices are selected but no audio.

I've also tried to create a Aggregate device in the Midi tool as suggested online but that hasn't worked. I've rebooted the machine several times, tried different USB ports but still no luck. It appears to be a specific issue with FaceTime as the other apps I've used have worked great.

I'd really appreciate any kind of suggestions to help resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you gone back to the Sound control panel to re-select the microphone once you've started FaceTime running?

Comment: It’s still selected in the sound panel but the audio bar doesn’t move once the FaceTime call starts.

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of Monterey?

Comment: Try **UN**-selecting it, close that preference pane, go back to it and re-select it. *some*times that works...